# How can Periscope App broadcast the video so successful?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, video-streaming, live-streaming

Twitter's new application Periscope broadcasts video. I watched a broadcast just a couple minutes ago first time and I wonder that how can it stream live video without any freezing or annoying freezing (Actually I didn't see any freezing but maybe there was somebody has) on 3g? 2 or 3 weeks ago I have tried Twitter's video post feature and it was a disastrous. What is the difference between live streaming and recorded video uploading? Or is it difference between iPhone and Android?

Comment: it uses HLS (HTTP Live Streaming). HLS is meant for producing smooth streaming. http://www.alamtechstuffs.com/periscope-livestreaming-app/

Comment: Also see this tech talk http://nerds.airbnb.com/building-periscope-for-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no secret, it's a well established technique which is not Twitter specific.

Uploaded videos are fetched using pseudo-streaming (progressive download) while the live stream is delivered using adaptive bitrate streaming which means there are multiple renditions of the same live stream for different bandwidths. The player can then choose one version that makes the most of your connection.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_bitrate_streaming

Comment: any there any open source/existing scalable proven backend solution to support realtime adaptive bitrate streaming?

Comment: @ronaldwidha: for **HLS** you can use the [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) for the **Nginx** web server which will create the variant playlists. You need to create the master playlists manually but it's trivial. For **DASH** there's the [GPAC DashCast](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/dashcast/).

Comment: HLS has a certain overhead that even in very short playlists will cause longer latency then you can see on Periscope on mobile. See my answer for a more detailed look at how.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is not that simple.
HLS is for example how they do it on the web and how Meerkat does that using short segment sizes to speed up the buffering and playlist creation that HLS creates.

On mobile they show a 2-3 seconds latency which I never saw using HLS.
Sniffing the connections themselves I see that on mobile they are using RTMP which is way more expensive and way less scalable to give that experience.

Here is a short article talking about that - note the comments about the rtmp playback:
http://www.alamtechstuffs.com/periscope-livestreaming-app/

Comment: So finally what is periscope using HLS or RTMP?

Comment: Periscope is using RTMP for native mobile apps. Money money money money - but results are good.
HLS on web.

Comment: Liviu when you say RTMP is expensive, do you mean it is resource intensive consumes more memory etc or it costs more money to buy rtmp streaming service or maintain one?

Comment: Both.
RTMP is more consuming in terms of data and sometimes CPU (depends on the player - but if it doesnt use the built in acceleration for sure) on the consumer device itself and RTMP service itself by the way its built scales poorly when compared to HLS.
To scale HLS you just need CDN / HTTP Servers that do no processing.
RTMP by definition you need to scale your consecutive connections which is no where near as cheap as downloading static files in a restful way.